# jQuery dialog shows with no theme when accessing from Facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, dialog, themes

I have a page I am using as Facebook application, this page shows a dialog to the user.
When I access this page directly, not from Facebook, it shows the dialog as expected, when I access the page as a Facebook application (from Facebook) the dialog shows with no theme.
Any idea why ?

Comment: Not really without seeing any code. Might be an issue with how your css path is written

Comment: Hi again, directory structure follows -
mySite/fb/Styles
Within the fb folder I have the aspx app page for FB and the link for the CSS follows -
**<link href="Styles/humanity/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />**

When browsing the page independently (not as a FB app) it shows fine, when browsing the page as a FB app seems like CSS is missing.